# jQuery repopulate the selected item in an option list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been trying to work this out for a little while now, no luck.

```
jQuery("#choosenCause option:selected").removeAttr("selected","selected");

jQuery('#choosenCause option[value="'+json.causeID+'"]').attr("selected",true);
```

I'm using the above, it adds `selected="selected"` to the right element, but does not change the selected element that the user sees.

Full JS here - http://inspire.simplyfundraising.co.uk/wp-content/themes/inspire/assets/js/promojs.js

Comment: Also, a minor thing... Choosen isn't a word. Chosen is. Choosen isn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the selected option of a `select` element, use `val()`:

```
jQuery('#choosenCause').val(json.causeID);
```

Comment: This is of course assuming that `#choosenCause` represents a `<select>` element...

Comment: You can see it in action here - http://inspire.simplyfundraising.co.uk/join-the-club/ try entering promo code COUPON1 you should...see the select box change to water aid. But nada.

Comment: @David that appears to be a different problem, how are you detecting what is being input into the coupon box?

Comment: Running the promo code through ajax checked and passed back json and then adjust the cause list with the cause attached to the promo code.

Comment: It appears to work, although it's selecting `Wolfwood`, not `Water aid`

Answer (score 0):

in the first string you need to correct the code - `jQuery("#choosenCause option:selected").removeAttr("selected");`
the second string works fine as i see